# Python version different with anaconda version

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I'm using python 3.9.0 and I want to install Anaconda, but the Anaconda not support python 3.9 yet. Is it okay if I'm still installing Anaconda ?

Comment: *"Is it okay if I'm still installing Anaconda?"* is python 3.9 absolutely necessary for your application? If not then simply install Anaconda and use that python... It won't be the latest version but you can always update it later on. Else don't install Anaconda and install all packages on you own using pip

Comment: Anaconda installs its own python distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda actually comes with its own bundled Python and its package libraries. It is still okay if you already have Python installed on your machine.

If Python 3.9 is not necessary for your application, you can use Anaconda bundled Python version i.e Python 3.8 (latest version as now).

You can run your Python script using Anaconda virtual environment, so you will not mess up with existing Python installation.